# Is this a correct theoretical concept of a simple electric current generator?

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, rotation

As I think I somehow understand electromagnetic induction and after watching several experiments on YouTube with magnet pieces left to fall through coils which had connected ends to permit the electric current to flow through them, I imagined how this feature can be used to easily generate electricity at home by just mechanical force...The problem was how to have the inductive piece to freely move through the coil and figured out that there should be some gears used to help this action...Please see the picture as it could help to understand what I am trying to present and ask for its functionality....This is just an exclusively theoretical question and not a engineering question so I decided to post it here and any positive comment or answer will be helpful for me as well as to other users to spot possible errors and help me to improve my basic idea....
In simple words does this idea make an automated version of the [men on Youtube video dropping the magnet and then pick up it and drop it again through the coil several times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc1pfeheZ74)?....
[image]

Comment: Why would a metal moving through a coil induce a voltage?

Comment: @Puk Terribly sorry, I should have been very distracted to not spot what huge error I made. Ofcourse there should be mentioned magnets instead pieces of metal. Again sorry...I will try to edit the question.....

Comment: "easily generate electricity" I  cannot follow such diagrams, but please keep in mind , if you are thinking of using the energy generated by a successful magnetic circuit , that the energy will come  out of the demagnetization of the permanent magnet.

Comment: @annav Please read the added text on the edited question and please can You answer does every 'pink magnet' on the torus on the picture replace the annoying iteration of the men on the video dropping the neodymium magnet through the coil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the exact device you are showing in the diagram, but as for the principle of moving a magnet through a coil of wire via mechanical energy input – this is how all electrical power in the world is generated, apart from solar (and niche devices like thermoelectric generators).  In order to create continuous motion and not have to "pick up the magnet and release" every time, a circular set of coils is used, and the magnets are spun using a turbine. The mechanical input is supplied by high pressure steam (boiled by fossil fields or nuclear or geothermal) or else by hydroelectric or wind power.

As far a generating electricity at home it is unlikely you will be able to power anything substantial like an appliance, but they do make emergency flash lights and radios powered by hand cranks, which you can experiment with.